# Crystal Report is not printing all the records when it come more than 23 records

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I am using c# and sql server i have created a POS system and it works fine but the problem is when we add more than 23 items it is not printing all the records. But hen we print less than 23 items it prints everything, Why i that? I gave page Horizontal 6.1 and vertical 40..... please some one help with this issue.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Print Button Code?

Comment: Any code that pertains to your problem yes.

Comment: System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument printDocument = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument(); rpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
                rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;

Comment: I have used this code for auto print, and also if there is 33 Items in the db it printing only 30 items, why is that? i think i better try with other report viewrs, can u suggess one?

Comment: Your code should be added to the question, not posted in a comment.  It should also be formatted properly, using the code formatting settings.